# Plugin using "Eclipse-BundleShape: dir" in the dropins directory

Tags: deployment, eclipse-plugin

I'm developing a plug-in which I'd prefer have installed as a directory, not as a jar file.

I'm using a `Eclipse-BundleShape: dir` entry in the `MANIFEST.MF` for this. When the plug-in is installed from an update site this work fine. But when installed by placing it in the `<ECLIPSE_ROOT>/dropins` directory the plug-in is found and works but the jar file is not unpacked to a directory.

If I manually unpack the plug-in and place it in `dropins` that also works, but that requires a manual step.

How can I have my plug-in become automatically unpacked to a directory when installed in the `dropins` directory?

Answer (score 0):

Did you give a try with "Unpack the plug-in archive after the installation" option from the feature plug-in?

http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.pde.doc.user%2Fguide%2Ftools%2Feditors%2Ffeature_editor%2Fplugins.htm

Comment: Since the feature zip file need to be unpacked before being placed in `dropins` this still requires a manual step to install the plug-in. It's also a bit inconvenient to have a feature for each and every plug-in, it would be better if it was possible to install the plug-in jars directly.